# What is best practice for patching a prior release?

Tags: git, github, version-control, semantic-versioning

I'm working on a project where we need to patch an old version of our library. We publish/release this package to GitHub Package Registry and (needless to say) use semantic versioning. This is our first time patching a prior release and I'm having a hard time identifying the best practice for this.

I came across [this](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/128#issuecomment-38799796) thread that mostly seems to work except for a couple issues albeit major ones. Following what was described in the comment I linked above, here are the steps I've tried in a test repo. In this example, let's assume there are two tags that exist on the `main` branch: `v1.0.0` and `v2.0.0`, and I need to patch the `v1.0.0` release with a hotfix (`v1.1.0`).

- checkout the v1.0.0 tag (`git checkout v1.0.0`)
- create a hotfix branch (`git checkout -b hotfix-v1.1.0`)
- 
- commit changes to hotfix branch (`git add .;git commit -m "Hotfix v1.1.0 changes"`)
- create hotfix tag on hotfix branch (`git tag v1.1.0`)
- switch to trunk (`git checkout main`)
- merge hotfix branch into trunk (`git merge hotfix-v1.1.0 --no-commit --strategy ours`)
- commit merge (which requires manual intervention) (`git commit`)
- push up hotfix tag (`git push --tags`)
- delete local hotfix branch (`git branch -d hotfix-v1.1.0`)

After these operations, I checked origin in GitHub and found that the `v1.1.0` hotfix *was* present in the latest commit (good) and the latest state of `main` had the code from `v2.0.0` (good). It also had the new `v1.1.0` tag (good).

There are a couple issues, though. First, when I switch to the hotfix tag (`v1.1.0`) in GitHub, there is the following alert: *"This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository."* I'm unclear on the implications of this, but it doesn't seem like a good thing.

The bigger issue is that the committing, merging, etc. I executed ignore the fact that my `main` branch is protected by various status checks. Being able to ensure existing workflows and checks are included in this hotfix process is a requirement.

So what is the best practice for patching a prior release? Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: 1.1.0 indicates new features were added since 1.0.0. A bug fix to 1.0.0 should be 1.0.1.

Comment: If you have a still supported, older major version to which you backport fixes, I feel like that should live on its own branch, since the v2 version likely introduced breaking changes, and juggling two major versions on the same branch might not be workable.

Comment: @Schwern Put aside whether the bug fix would be a patch release vs. minor release. Also, that gitflow doc does not address either issue I described, correct?

Comment: @BenjaminW. The backporting scenario you described is what I'm talking about. Does the multiple branch situation you mention require the hotfix tags to live only on the non-main branch and require that branch to not be deleted?

Comment: That's how I think I'd do it, but I'm not sure what other options there even are. Have you checked out larger open source projects that maintain multiple major versions?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I looked at Ant Design, but there is only so much you can grok from looking at tags/branches. I need to understand the process.

Comment: What is "it" in this sentence: "It also had the new v1.1.0 tag (good)." ? Also, I'm not seeing anywhere stating that you actually pushed `main` after updating it, only that you pushed the tagged hotfix. If you did push `main`, then maybe your branch protection isn't working as expected. Side note, status checks are for PRs, and had you created your new version of `main` on a temporary branch and created a PR into `main` with it, it's possible that your status checks would all instantly pass because that PR would presumably have 0 changes in the diff, since you merged with `-s ours`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just address the issues you're having with your current workflow.

Moving forward, you likely want a variation on [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/) where you make a release branch off v1.0.0 and leave it open. If you want those fixes also in v2 you'd  [cherry pick](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick) them back into v2 in a separate feature branch. You would **not** merge v1 into v2, this risks conflicts and resurrecting old v1 code in v2.

---

> The bigger issue is that the committing, merging, etc. I executed ignore the fact that my main branch is protected by various status checks. Being able to ensure existing workflows and checks are included in this hotfix process is a requirement.

The problem is you're merging locally where there are no checks. No workflow should be merging nor committing directly to main.

Instead, merge using [pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests). This allows checks to run on the branch and review to happen *before* merging to main.

---

> First, when I switch to the hotfix tag (v1.1.0) in GitHub, there is the following alert: "This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository." I'm unclear on the implications of this, but it doesn't seem like a good thing.

**NOTE**: v1.1.0 indicates new features have been added. A release containing only bugfixes should be v1.0.1.

Despite what `git log` and Github show, Git history is *not* linear. It is a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)). Each commit is connected to its previous commit(s). You can see this with `git log --graph --decorate` or a tool such as [Git Kraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/).

Branches and tags are just labels which point at a commit.

What Git is telling you is the commit is not reachable from any branch.

Let's walk through how this happened.

You start like this:

```
local
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F [main]

origin
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F [main]
```

Commits only connect to the left. D can reach C, B, and A. C cannot reach D.

The v1.0.0 tag points at commit C. The main branch points at commit F.

A, B, C, D, E, and F are all reachable from main.

Here both your local repository and the copy on Github (your "origin" remote) are the same.

```
#    checkout the v1.0.0 tag (git checkout v1.0.0)
#    create a hotfix branch (git checkout -b hotfix-v1.1.0)
#    commit changes to hotfix branch (git add .;git commit -m "Hotfix v1.1.0 changes")
#    create hotfix tag on hotfix branch (git tag v1.1.0)

local
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F [main]
         \
          G {v1.1.0}
            [hotfix-v1.1.0]

origin
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F [main]
```

You've made your hotfix branch, added a commit, and tagged it.

hotfix can only reach G, C, B, and A.

G is **not** reachable from main.

Nothing has been pushed to Github.

```
#    switch to trunk (git checkout main)
#    merge hotfix branch into trunk (git merge hotfix-v1.1.0 --no-commit --strategy ours)
#    commit merge (which requires manual intervention) (git commit)

local
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F - M [main]
         \             /
          G -----------
           {v1.1.0}
           [hotfix-v1.1.0]

origin
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F [main]
```

You've merged your hotfix branch into main. M is a merge commit with both F and G as its parents. Locally, G (and thus v1.1.0) is part of both the main branch and hotfix branch.

```
# push up hotfix tag (git push --tags)
# delete local hotfix branch (git branch -d hotfix-v1.1.0)

local
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F - M [main]
         \             /
          G -----------
           {v1.1.0}

origin
         {v1.0.0}
A - B - C - D - E - F [main]
         \
          G {v1.1.0}
```

Here's where it went wrong. Git push/pull is *very* efficient and will only push as much as it needs. Since you only pushed tags, it only pushed the commits it needed to populate the history of your tags. That means it only pushed commit G.

So as far as Github is concerned, commit G cannot be reached by any branch. This isn't necessarily a bad thing, the commit can still be referenced via the tag.

If you `git push --all` Git will push all your tags and branches, and any commits necessary to populate their history. That means it will push that main now points at M. This means it must push commit M. Then G will be connected to main on Github.